# Big Problems upgrading Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

well I have to update from cordova 2.5.0 to cordova 2.9.0 - so I have to update first from 2.5. to 2.6 to...2.9.0
I'm always having troubles with these upgrades, because I'm not a native speaker and might get the documentation on cordova.apache.org wrong

Ok here is where I'm stuck right now:
I have to run the create command with the following parameters:
- Path to your new Cordova iOS project
- Package name, following reverse-domain style convention
- Project name

2 questions:
- is the command-line-tool the terminal
- what is meant by package-name? Is is important, that this new project should have the same package-name and reverse-domain-style like my real project i want to upgrade from 2.5 to 2.x?

Sorry if this is a ridicolous question, but I'm really desperate right now :(
Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link which will help you to upgrade your existing PhoneGap application.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html

Yes you need to use the terminal for using command line tool.

Package name is used for unique identification for your app. So it is important as the same package name you also need to declare in your provisioning certificate for iOS . So you need to give the same package name as in your existing project.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer - but I'm developing for iOS and used this doc http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html  I hope its the right one. So I should give the new project the exact same reverse domain, then my existing project? Won't there be any difficulties with references later or do I just copy and paste snippets from the files in the new project into my existing one (and erase the new project later)?

Comment: There should not be any issue . After creating new project you just need to copy the www folder of the existing project and put it inside your new project directory.

Comment: Ok thanks again - one question: Do I have to upgrade from 2.5 to 2.6 to...2.9 or is it possible to just upgrade from 2.5 to 2.9?

Comment: If you want to upgrade from 2.5 to 2.9 directly, you need to create new project using 2.9 version and move all source code to new project. Other wise you need to follow this guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html It will upgrade in step wise manner, like 2.5 to 2.6 then 2.6 to 2.7 and so on.

Comment: Ok great, that's what I'm up to right now - the package nam is similar to the bundle-identifier to the project, right? Because thats the only reverse domain I found in my xcodeproj

Comment: Ok i will check it out later (have to go to work now) and will let you know if it worked ;) Thanks for your help so far

Comment: right now I'm not really sure if I'm doing it right (it was over a year ago since I created a new phone gap-project) - i just write the direction of the bin-folder (.../phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin) and then the destination where the new xcodeproj should be with the bundle-id? I'm asking this because I don't want do anything wrong which can't be undone (and maybe creates difficulties). Is this correct?

Comment: There should not be any problem. Any way you existing project will be there. You are only moving the source code to new project and if you have used any external plugins in your old project then you need to add the same in new project.

Comment: Ok today we have holidays here and I had enough time to do it - it worked (like you always told). Thank you. I'd like to give you a reputation-point, but I do need 2 more reputation-points myself to be able to give others points ;)